# How to solve when I got http error in localhost in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ruby2 and rails 4.0.2 . My problem is when I want to check list of url in localhost(typing wrong url in address bar so that I can see the list) it shows http error. How can I solve this problem? If any one have any idea please share with me. I am attaching an image what I got.

[image]

You can see in image I wrote

"localhost:3000/static_pages/ind"

instead of

"localhost:3000/static_pages/index"

and I got http error.

I am expecting something like this:

[image]

Comment: What environment do you run? Is it development? If so, show your `development.rb` file.

Comment: Please check you Route file

Comment: As much I understood and I know `404` is a `Record Not Found ` error, and you got it because `localhost:3000/static_pages/ind` this url will search in `static_pages` for `ind` as there is no action associated to it as a `id` and there is no record with `ind` id, so you are getting that error. you can try `localhost:3000/static_pages/`

Comment: localhost:3000/static_pages/  This is also giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify:

```
# Show full error reports
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

in your `config/environments/<environment>.rb` file. Check that this option set to `true`. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) is details.

Answer (score -1):

To show your app routes in the terminal (the list that you are looking for) you can run `rake routes` in a terminal.

As the output is usually noisy, I use it with grep like follows:

```
rake routes | grep user
```